# Get UITableViewCell of UIButton?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to perform a segue using a `UIButton`, which is located within in a custom `UITableViewCell` class called `GFHomeCell`.

The `GFHomeCell` has a `postID` property, which I want to send in the prepare for segue. I set up a method to run when the button is pressed; however, in the button-pressed method, I need the sender to be a `GFHomeCell`(or at least that's what I assume).

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do that? Here is my code

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
        GFHomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newsfeedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSDictionary *rootObject = self.posts[indexPath.row];
        NSDictionary *post = rootObject[@"post"];
        NSDictionary *group = post[@"group"];

        NSString *groupName = group[@"name"];

        cell.actionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New post trending on %@", groupName];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = post[@"body"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.likesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", post[@"likes"]];
        cell.postId = post[@"id"];
        cell.groupName = group[@"name"];
        cell.postBody = post[@"body"];
        cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cell.commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentButtonClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s/%@", kBaseURL, @"images/"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Newsfeed-Image-Placeholder"]];

        return cell;
```

Here is the method I'm running when the button is clicked. My thought was that I need the sender here to be a cell, not a button, as the `postId` property I'm sending in my `prepareForSegue` only exists on a `GFHomeCell`:

```
- (void)commentButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addCommentSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

Finally my `prepareForSegue`(I only included the part relevant to this segue):

```
} else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addCommentSegue"]) {
   GFPostShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    GFHomeCell * cell = sender;

    destViewController.postId = [cell.postId copy];
    destViewController.groupName = [cell.groupName copy];
    destViewController.postBody = [cell.postBody copy];

} else {}
```

I'm new to iOS and this has me stumped so any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: one common idiom is to set the tag on each cell's button to something that lets you get back to the cell -- could be an array index or the cell row (if there's only one section). Then in the button click event handler you just access sender.tag and off you go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two common approaches to this situation. One is to search up through the button's superviews until you find the cell. You shouldn't rely on going up one or two levels, because the hierarchy has changed in the past, and may change again (you need to go up two levels in iOS 6, but 3 in iOS 7). You can do it like this,

```
-(void)commentButtonClick:(UIButton *) sender {
    id superView = sender.superview;
    while (superView && ![superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        superView = [superView superview];
    }
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addCommentSegue" sender:superView];
}
```

The other way is to assign a tag to your button in cellForRowAtIndexPath: equal to the indexPath.row (if you only have one section), and then use sender.tag to get the indexPath of the cell that contained the tapped button.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you give me an example of what the method would look like for the second approach. Is it just sender.tag in the sender box or am I going to use sender.tag to get the cell.

Comment: @jckly, I would still use sender as the argument in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:, and then in the prepareForSegue:sender: method, use sender.tag to get the row that contained the button. You should then get the data from the object at that index in your array, rather than getting the data from the cell. It's generally not a good idea to get data out of a cell, cells are for displaying data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one answer would be to just go up a level in the view hierarchy:

```
 - (void)commentButtonClick:(id)sender {
    GFHomeCell * cell = (GFHomeCell *) [(UIButton*)sender superview];
    if (cell && [cell Class] == [GFHomeCell class]) {
        //do whatever with cell.postID
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addCommentSegue" sender:sender];
     }
}
```

Oh, I forget... you may have to go up two levels to get past the contentView property:

```
   GFHomeCell * cell = (GFHomeCell *) [[(UIButton*)sender superview] superview];
```

Comment: this is a pretty fragile way to do it though

Comment: Agreed...Should have remembered that I ran into that myself on the iOS7 transition!