# Get reference to UITableViewCell from IBAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios8

I have a tableview that uses a UIButton in a custom UITableViewCell that triggers an IBAction in my view controller. In IOS7 I was able to reference the specific cell the action was triggered from by doing this `UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview]superview]`.

This worked fine in iOS7, however it seems in iOS8 it requires one of the `superview`s to be removed to return the cell, otherwise it returns nil. So I'm doing it this way now, and it works, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to implement this. I just don't like the way this looks.

```
 UITableViewCell *clickedCell;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
     clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview]superview];
}
else{
     clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview]superview];
}
```

Comment: A better way is to search up through the button's superviews until you find the cell. Look at my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949304/get-uitableviewcell-of-uibutton/22950960#22950960

Comment: Oddly I'm getting `Property 'superview' not found on object of type '__strong id'` on `id superView = sender.superview`, which makes no sense because it doesn't know what kind of class it is, how could it know what properties it does and doesn't have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass the UIButton to MYButton and add a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableViewCell *parentCell;
```

Then, when you set up the UIButton from the cell set parentCell = self

From there you could simply access the cell by:

```
MYButton *button = (MYButton *)sender;
clickedCell = sender.parentCell.
```

Make sure to use a weak property so you do not create a retain cycle.