# Accessing custom cell object properties on tap of UIButton in same cell SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom cell setup with an add and subtract button, and a quantity label. I'd like a label in the view controller to update with the price shown in the cell.

I've scoured SE and the google machine, but all examples are for Objective-C and are satisfied with passing the `indexPath.row` to the selector. I've managed to pass the row in which the add button was tapped to the selector method, however I can't access the objects in the cell, e.g `cell.itemNameLabel.text`

I've tried implementing in the selector method something similar to the objective-c: with no joy.

```
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Here is my setup:

Custom Cell:

```
class ProductListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var itemNameLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView! = UIImageView()
@IBOutlet var itemPriceLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet weak var itemQty: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addItem: UIButton! = UIButton()
```

Main view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:ProductListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProductListTableViewCell

    let drink:PFObject = self.productListData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    cell.itemImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.itemImage.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.itemImage.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.addItem.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addItem.addTarget(self, action:("cellAddItemAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    cell.itemNameLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("name") as? NSString
    cell.calorieLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("calories") as? NSString

    cell.itemPriceLabel.text = drink.objectForKey("price") as? NSString
    cell.itemImage.alpha = 1

    let itemImage = drink["image"] as PFFile

    itemImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.itemImage.image = image
        }

    }
    }
)
    return cell
}
```

Selector method:

```
func cellAddItemAction(sender: UIButton){

    println("pressed \(sender.tag)")

}
```

This works but I need to make changes to the objects in the cell, such as cell.itemQty.text.

Hope this is clear, i'm quite new to programming so please be patient with my terminology, I know its not all right!! Thanks for helping.

Comment: The cell is not the superview of your button. you need to go up through the view hierarchy to find the cell. Look at my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949304/get-uitableviewcell-of-uibutton/22950960#22950960

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still a bit baffled though. In your answer you say "The other way is to assign a tag to your button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` equal to the `indexPath.row` (if you only have one section), and then use `sender.tag` to get the indexPath of the cell that contained the tapped button" which is what i've already done. Or have I? I also lack the research skills to convert your answer into swift which doesn't help!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I went about it slightly differently. This is a prototype app and needs only to appear to work. Heres what I did if it helps anyone though.

Add a tag to the button being pressed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

`cell.addItem.tag = indexPath.row`

Then when adding the target, instead of using Self, use the cell:

`cell.addItem.addTarget(cell, action:("cellAddItemAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

Declare a global variable in the viewController:

`let priceUpdateKey = "com.ordr.priceUpdateKey"`

Now write the function inside the cell class, and add the NSNotification method, sending your data in the userInfo parameter

```
func cellAddItemAction(sender: UIButton){

    var count = (String(self.itemQty.text!)).toInt()!
    totalPrice = (self.itemPriceLabel!.text! as NSString).doubleValue

    count += 1

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(priceUpdateKey, object: nil, userInfo: ["totalPrice":totalPrice])

}
```

Then back in the viewController, add an observer for the NSNotification:

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updatePrice:", name: priceUpdateKey, object: nil)`

And finally write the function that the observer calls:

```
func updatePrice(sender: NSNotification) {

    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,Double!> = sender.userInfo as Dictionary<String,Double!>
    let messagePrice = userInfo["totalPrice"]
    let finalCalc = totalAmount + messagePrice!
    totalAmount = finalCalc

    totalPriceButton.setTitle("£\(totalAmount)0", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}'
```

Note** I'm not claiming this is a good method, but it works for me, and if it helps you, perfect.

Comment: This is really not the correct way to do this. You shouldn't access the cell to retrieve values from a label, you should get that string from your data source (the array you use to populate the table). In your original code, you've given the button a tag based on the indexPath.row. Use that tag in your button's action method as the index  into your array. Update the array with the new data, and then call reloadData on your table view to update the cells.